React & VsCode forwardRef Intellisense
I am trying to get intellisense in VSCode working for functional components that use forwardRef.
Assume a functional component like this:
const Slider = forwardRef(({value = 0, onChange = () => { /* some function */ }}, ref) => {
  return "whatever"
})
export default Slider;

If i use this component somewhere else, the props value and onChange are not suggested by intellisense. I am not using typescript, so is there any workaround to get intellisense working in this case without adding much overhead?
I just found suggestions for typescript implementations, but not for this approach.

Consider TypeScript?

The only thing you can do in this situation is to use JSDoc comments in order to help VSCode to be able to make suggestions. Something like this
/**
 * @typedef {Object} SliderProps
 * @property {number} [value] - The current value of the slider.
 * @property {function(number):void} [onChange] - Callback function triggered when the value changes.
 */

/**
 * Slider component
 * @param {SliderProps} props
 * @param {React.Ref} ref - Forwarded ref for the slider element.
 * @returns {React.ReactElement} The Slider component.
 */
const Slider = forwardRef(...)


You can use JSDoc comment:
/**
 * @param {object} props
 * @param {number} [props.value=0] - The slider value
 * @ param {function} [props.onChange] - The change handler function 
 */
const Slider = f…

